# Execute mixed sql: dynamic with static

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute mixed sql: dynamic with static. I have a `stored proc` with many queries and `select-into-temp-table` constructions. Portions of it need to be dynamic. Here are some extracted snippets of what I'm trying to do:

```
@DynamicPrefix = '0001' -- this is passed in by caller
@EngineCd = '070123456' -- this is passed in by caller

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @EngineKey INT

SET @DynamicSQL = 'set @EngineKey = (select optionnumber from lookup_' + @DynamicPrefix + '_option_001 
where salescode = ' + @EngineCd + ')'
EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

Then further down:

```
Select MyCol
into #Eng
from myTable
where EngineKey = @EngineKey
```

There's a lot of static sql before, in between, and after my code block above.

The whole reason I'm bothering about dynamic sql is because I don't know certain table names until run time. So `@DynamicPrefix` enables me to construct the correct table names at execution time.

I can create the proc without errors, but when I run it I get the error **Must declare the scalar variable "@EngineKey"**. It's clear to me that because @EngineKey is inside dynamic sql, it's invisible from within the static sql further down.

I suspect I need to use `exec sp_executesql` but I can't quite figure out the usage, so I had just started with EXEC.

How can I get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forget `DECLARE`

Comment: Those first 2 vars are passed in, it's really declared in the param list for the proc. Is that what you're referring to? When it's all static it works fine, there are no missing declares. When I begin making it dynamic is when it breaks.

Comment: You should add theparameters datatypes and values

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql#syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
@DynamicPrefix = '0001'; -- this is passed in by caller
@EngineCd = '070123456'; -- this is passed in by caller

DECLARE @EngineKey INT;


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX);

SET @SQL =N'set @EngineKey = (select optionnumber from lookup_'+
    @DynamicPrefix +
    '_option_001 where salescode = '+
    @EngineCd +')';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQL,
    N'@EngineKey INT OUTPUT, @EngineCd VARCHAR(10)',
    @EngineKey OUTPUT, @EngineCd;
```

You have to specify your output parameter with `OUTPUT` keyword, and set your variables and their datatypes as you can see in the code.

If you don't use the `OUTPUT` keyword, your variable will always return `NULL`.

There are examples provided in the docs, see **[sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql#examples)**.

Comment: Sami this is GREAT except that I could only get it to work by placing the sql in a var, and then handing the var into sp_executesql, like this: `SET @SQL = N'set @EngineKey = ........'` Shoving it directly into the sp_executesql call simply wouldn't work for me - it complained about the concatenation. After I made that change it works. If you'll mod your solution (either my way or some other way that works) I will accept it.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder No need to `SET @SQL =`,  just write `EXECUTE sp_executesql
        N'set @EngineKey.....`, no need to `DynamicSQL` variable at all.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder error msg please and the length of EngineCd  variable

Comment: Do string concatenation directly in your sp_executesql and you can't even create the proc. Error: `Incorrect syntax near '+'.` Works fine though if you put it into a var first. Try it yourself and see.